# How to debug a React-Application from IntelliJ in 2023/2024

Tags: react-native, debugging, intellij-idea

I try to setup my development Environment to be able to debug my local react application and I have problems.
Running the react-Application in run-mode from Intellij works well. IntelliJ opens the app in a chrome browser succesfully. [image]

But with Debug [image] I get the message:
"Waiting for connection to localhost:45836.  Please ensure that the browser was started successfully with remote debugging port opened. Port cannot be opened if Chrome having the same User Data Directory is already launched."

I followed the instructions from:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html

both plugins are installed:
[image]
.
[image]

I setup a new Chrome with own data folder. I assigned this Browser to the run-configuration "Javascript-Debug"

[image]
[image]

Before start debug I have closed all other chrome browsers. So its a fresh window.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the old IDE version (2019.x?). In IDE versions < 2022.2.5, 2022.3.4, 2023.1 (i.e., released before March 2023), similar symptoms can be caused by Chrome update: Chrome 111.* released in March 2023 broke the debugger as it rejects the requests from unknown remote origins due to security fixes.
If upgrading the IDE is not an option, you can try passing `--remote-allow-origins=*` option to Chrome; the option has to be specified in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers and Preview**, in the **Chrome Settings** dialog that opens when you select `Chrome` configuration there and press **Edit**.